# How to have generic template to a member in a class in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create a global property settings for my application.

I'm gonna use templates, but something I'm not able to achieve is the use of template withing a map inside another class take a look:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;


template <typename T> 
class GlobalValue 
{
public:
    GlobalValue(const T& value)
        : value(value)
    {
    }

    T GetValue() { return value; }
    void SetValue(T val) { value = val; }

private:
    T value;
};

class GlobalSettings
{
private:
    map<string, shared_ptr<GlobalValue<T>>> map; // Error (active)  E0020   identifier "T" is undefined

};
```

in this case obviously I get T undefined.

if I put like this:

```
class GlobalSettings
{
public:
    template <typename T> map<string, shared_ptr<GlobalValue<T>>> map;
};
```

I got Error (active)    E0786   member "GlobalSettings::map" is not a valid class member template

I could do this, but I dont want the user of GlobalSettings to declare a global type, I want the map to be very decoupled:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;


template <typename T> 
class GlobalValue 
{
public:
    GlobalValue(const T& value)
        : value(value)
    {
    }

    T GetValue() { return value; }
    void SetValue(T val) { value = val; }

private:
    T value;
};

template <typename T>
class GlobalSettings
{
public:
    map<string, shared_ptr<GlobalValue<T>>> map;
};
```

Another option could be using this, but this is not good design I think:

```
class GlobalSettings
{
public:
    map<string, shared_ptr<void*>> map;
};
```

**so my question is:
is there a way to create a map inside a class that has a template style field but not to be declared it globally?**

Comment: Have you read about `std::any`?

Comment: Templates are just templates. If you do not make `GlobalSettings` a template as well, you have no way to deduce what the inner `T` is, so your map member cannot be instantiated. So for what you ask, templates may not be the right thing to use. But IMHO, such a strange requirement is probably a sign of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Or, if the set of T is finite, `std::variant`.

Comment: Using a json libray might help (as json is (to simplify) a "variant")...

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. You'd have to access the actual map with map.value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class GlobalValue
{
public:
    GlobalValue(const T& value)
        : value(value)
    {
    }

    T GetValue() { return value; }
    void SetValue(T val) { value = val; }

private:
    T value;
};

template <typename T>
struct GlobalValueMap
{
    map<string, shared_ptr<GlobalValue<T>>> value;
};


class GlobalSettings
{
private:
    GlobalValueMap<int> map;
};
```